# Print CI with esttab in a specific order Stata

Tags: stata, confidence-interval

I´m trying to print my CI with esttab in this order:

[image]

My code with the cars.csv dataset form https://gist.github.com/noamross/e5d3e859aa0c794be10b#file-cars-csv:

```
clear all
import excel "C:\Users\luism\Desktop\archive/cars_usa.xlsx", sheet("hoja1") firstrow

destring mileage, force replace

reg price mileage
estimates store model_1

esttab model_1 using "C:\Users\luism\Desktop\archive/results.csv", replace beta ci
```

This is what I got when I separate by commas the results.csv file.

[image]

I would like to print the upper bound below the lower bound, not next to after I separate by commas the results.csv. Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure `esttab` or `estout` doesn't have that option. You might have to code this yourself by taking the results from r(table) and writing it to an Excel file with `putexcel`.

Comment: You might be able to add the CI UB and LB as two separate auxiliary statistics, like N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`estadd` allows you to add anything as a scalar and include it as follows:

```
sysuse auto , clear
reg price mpg 
matrix results = r(table)
estadd scalar upperCI = results[rownumb(results,"ul"),colnumb(results,"mpg")]
estadd scalar lowerCI = results[rownumb(results,"ll"),colnumb(results,"mpg")]
esttab, stats(lowerCI upperCI)
```

This is exactly what Dimitry was suggesting in his comment. Wouter's comment is true to the extent that this isn't, strictly speaking, an "option" of `esttab` or `estout`. However, `estadd` provides a large amount of flexibility to `esttab` and it's worth knowing about.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I was looking for.